# Oracle apex functionality to send users option to set password

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-19.1

I am developing a ticketing application and using custom authentication using below function.

```
create or replace FUNCTION f_val_leave_user_issue(p_username IN VARCHAR2,
                                            p_password IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN BOOLEAN IS
  lv_char CHAR(1);
  lv_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'x'
  INTO   lv_char
  FROM   p_it_people
  WHERE  upper(p_username) = upper(person_username)
  AND    p_password = person_password;
  apex_util.set_authentication_result(0);
  RETURN TRUE;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    apex_util.set_authentication_result(4);
    RETURN FALSE;
END f_val_leave_user_issue;
```

As of now it takes username and password from p_it_people table, which i use in my login page.

Can i customize it further so that whenever there is a new user created in p_it_people, that user is prompted to set his own password and after setting,that password is automatically stored in p_it_people table??

Comment: Not in this function, no.  You can build that logic into the login page.  You should not be storing users' passwords in plain text by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure not to save passwords in the database as clear text.
I recommend reading this blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/custom-authentication-and-authorization-using-built-in-apex-access-control-a-how-to

You only save the hash value of the password in the database and every time a user login you need to hash their password and compare the two hashes.

Resetting the password is simply allowing the end-user to change his saved hash password.